# How to rotate gmaps?

Tags: android, google-maps, rotation

I'm using in my android app a WebView to show gmaps and I'm using javascript to change gmaps options.
Now I want to rotate the map according to the direction between two markers.

How can I achieve this? There is a gmap function?

ps: I see the "setHeading" function in gmap doc, but I can't make it work.

Comment: a GMap inside webview... Is that really usable?

Comment: Yes, it's good for some things. Not so good for other ones!
...but it's good if you know javascript!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. This is not supported yet:
http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=2515

So I think I have to use Google Maps Android API v2.